# How do I add a variable to a doskey command that will read the variable after it executes (not get the current variable)

Tags: variables, cmd, command, command-prompt, doskey

I have this command:

`doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& echo "You are in: "%cd%`

`doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& title %cd%`

When I paste this in CMD it will set the current cd and not dynamically when I recall the cd from the doskey.

Current output:

```
C:\>doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& echo "You are in: "%cd%

C:\>cd Users
You are in: C:\

C:\Users>
```

Desired output:

```
C:\>doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& echo "You are in: "%cd%

C:\>cd Users
You are in: C:\Users

C:\Users>
```

What I have tried:

`doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& echo "You are in: "%%cd%`

`doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& %cd%|echo "You are in: "`

`doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& cmd /k "echo \"You are in: \"%cd%"` < don't want a new cmd session!

Finally I want to add this to my register

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmdmenua]
@="Open Command Prompt Here (Admin)"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmdmenua\command]
@="powershell -NoLogo  -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \"$V = '%V'; Start-Process cmd \\\"/k  $($V.Substring(0,2)) & cd \"$V\" & Title Administrator: $V & doskey cd = cd /d `$* ^&^& title `$*\\\" -Verb RunAs\" "


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdmenua]
@="Open Command Prompt Inside (Admin)"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdmenua\command]
@="powershell -NoLogo  -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \"$V = '%V'; Start-Process cmd \\\"/k  $($V.Substring(0,2)) & cd \"$V\" & Title Administrator: $V & doskey cd = cd /d `$* ^&^& title `$* \\\" -Verb RunAs\" "
```

source: https://github.com/ScriptsAndApps/Context-REG

Comment: First of all you should not add/modify directly within, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, you should replace that with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`. Better however, IMO, based upon your intended resulting subkey values and data would be to change that to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead. I say that because this sort of thing should not be a setting for all users of the PC. In addition if you use the latter, you could add the information to the registry using `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe`, and that could be done without elevation, (`LOCAL_MACHINE` and `regedit.exe` require elevation).

Comment: What about `doskey cd=cd /D $* $T echo You are in: %^^CD%`? (not absolutely sure whether one `^` was sufficient)

Comment: @aschipfl YES this what I needed!! doskey cd=cd /D $* $T echo You are in: %^CD%

and

doskey cd=cd /D $* $T TITLE Administrator: %^CD%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for!

```
(
 @echo off
 doskey cd=cd /D $* $T echo You are in: %^CD% 
)
```

And this is what I will use

```
doskey cd=cd /D $* $T TITLE Administrator: %^CD%
```